# How can I find Arduino's UART COM port in MAC / Linux

Tags: uart

I'm using Arduino DUE with a Windows 7 machine.

In Windows, I can check the list of ports(COM & LPT) at the "Device Manager".

What about in MAC OSX or Linux (Ubuntu)?

-Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the device by using

```
dmesg | grep tty
```

after plugging it in.