# How to Set Up Modbus Poll Connection via USB to RS485 on Parallels Desktop for Mac

Tags: macos, modbus, parallels, rs485, com-port

I'm running Modbus Poll on a Mac through Parallels Desktop and am trying to connect to a Modbus device using a USB to RS485 converter. I'm having trouble determining the correct COM port to use within the Modbus Poll settings. Could someone guide me on:

1. How to identify the USB port in Parallels that corresponds to the physical USB connection?
2. Are there any additional configurations required within Modbus Poll to communicate over this USB port?

I've manually tried selecting different COM ports in the Modbus Poll connection settings, but I'm not sure which one corresponds to the USB device.
I've checked the Parallels settings to ensure USB devices are connected to the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to suggest some items:

- You are running `Parallels Desktop for Mac`
- By default there are no any COM ports on Mac's (MacBook, MacMini, iMac).
- You can connect your 485 adapter to guest OS.
- If there are no any Legacy COM ports inside the VM your adapter will be the ONLY ONE com port in the system.

Look at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM` registry path for available COM ports (source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19823450/3868464)).

[image]

Also you can do some system calls like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1205515/3868464).

On *nix guest OS you can try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44041843/3868464)